# Unable to install nvidia-driver-495 and nvidia-dkms-495

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia

For a few days I've been trying to install a driver for my GeForce RTX 3050. I need the laptop for machine learning, not gaming, and for that I need CUDA support.

However, the install for nvidia-driver-495, or nvidia-driver-470 keeps failing. It looks to me as if this failure is dependent on the failure of nvidia-dkms-495 or nvidia-dkms-470, respectively.

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 with a 5.13.0-20-generic kernel. I've seen posts that the missing firmware is not the issue, but if that needs to be resolved I am unsure how to do that.

Below you will find the trace for the failed (re)install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-495 is already the newest version (495.44-0ubuntu0.21.10.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up nvidia-dkms-495 (495.44-0ubuntu0.21.10.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Removing old nvidia-495.44 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 495.44
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-495.44 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-20-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.13.0-20-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-495.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/495.44/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-495 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-495 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-495:
 nvidia-driver-495 depends on nvidia-dkms-495 (<= 495.44-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-495 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-495 depends on nvidia-dkms-495 (>= 495.44); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-495 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-495 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-20-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_smc.bin for module amdgpu
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-495
 nvidia-driver-495
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't seem to figure out what the actual error is.

Comment: The actual error is that the kernel module doesn't build. And the message says where to look for more details. `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/495.44/build/make.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete /var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-495*.crash

(re)install `linux-firmware`

Open `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab, and select the nouveau driver. Then reboot.

Purge all Nvidia software.

`dpkg -l *nvidia*` should all show as `un` for uninstalled.

`dkms status` should show no nvidia kernel modules.

Open `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab, and select the Nvidia 495 driver. Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have been solved this by installing `gcc-9.3` and then retrying to install from software ubuntu app