# Nvidia driver installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management

I am trying to reinstall my Nvidia driver I removed everything and then installed it again using:

```
sudo apt autoremove nvidia* --purge
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I tried installing another driver such as the 525 the installation worked perfectly fine but then it made my computer slow and freeze a lot

But every single time I try to install the 535 driver I get this at the end:

```
nvidia-drm.ko: OK
nvidia-modeset.ko: OK
nvidia-peermem.ko: OK
nvidia-uvm.ko: OK
nvidia.ko: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-33-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-33-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 depends on linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-33-generic (= 6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1); however:
  Package linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-33-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libnvidia-encode-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-535:
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (<= 535.86.05-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not installed.
  Package linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 which provides nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (>= 535.86.05); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not installed.
  Package linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 which provides nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-535 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.37-7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-33-generic
 linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04
 nvidia-driver-535
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install nvidia-driver-495 and nvidia-dkms-495](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373334/unable-to-install-nvidia-driver-495-and-nvidia-dkms-495)